# No objects to concatenate when reading parquets from an S3 Prefix

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to obtain the daily appended dataframe of the files(dataframes) that are in the same month (current). By Cloudformation and Lambda function in Python.

This is what I'm doing now:

```py
    import boto3
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime

    S3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = S3.Bucket('cep-dev-bl-mkt')

    
    li = []
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='/totem/NOB_COD_DIAS/'):
        if obj.key.endswith('.parquet') and obj.last_modified.month == datetime.now().month:
            df = pd.read_parquet(f's3://{bucket.name}/{obj.key}')
            li.append(df)

    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "No objects to concatenate",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "requestId": "d5a11c60-e404-4d1b-9302-c90eaf19c201",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/src/lambda_function.py\", line 97, in lambda_handler\n    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/util/_decorators.py\", line 331, in wrapper\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py\", line 368, in concat\n    op = _Concatenator(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py\", line 425, in __init__\n    raise ValueError(\"No objects to concatenate\")\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to use `pd.concat` on an empty list.

Your list `li` will be empty if there are no objects matching your filter.

My guess is that the leading slash in the filter condition `/totem/NOB_COD_DIAS/` should be removed unless your object keys *explicitly* start with a leading slash.

Currrently, you're trying to read objects equivalent to this glob pattern:

```
s3://cep-dev-bl-mkt//totem/NOB_COD_DIAS/**.parquet
```

(Note the second double-slash)